# Android web service call asynchronously every 5 seconds

Tags: android

I want to call one web service after every 5 seconds in 1 min. Means in 1 min i want to call webservice 12 times. I want to do this asynchronously.

```
class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeScreen.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused)
    {

        return(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

          this.dialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

I know this can be done with this code. bt doinbackground only executes once. I can not implement timer also in doInBackground method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really easy way is to do this is just to implemented a TimerTask that creates and executes your AsyncTask.  Using your above AddStringTask:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        new AddStringTask().execute();
    }
}, 0, 5000);
```

Please note that even if you do implement this in a service, the service code will still run on the main GUI thread, so you need a separate thread or an async task to do the blocking operations for you.

Comment: Timer basically hang my activity screen.

Comment: I'm not sure how a timer could block your main thread, where are you constructing it?

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  There's no way a timer create/schedule is blocking your main thread.  EDIT: Since your AsyncTask Pre/PostExecute() methods are now executing on the Timer thread rather than the main thread, you'll get exceptions when you try to mess with GUI stuff.  You need to post runnables back to the gui thread.  Try getting rid of the GUI code and see if that helps, then I'll edit my main answer.

Comment: And since you're doing GUI stuff, you may just want to implement your network code in the TimerTask.run() method instead of going through all the AsyncTask / Post syntax that isn't really getting you anything.

Answer (score 0):

Go for a service rather then an async task for this.PFB the details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Hope this helps!